# Potential race condition on Combine's @Published property wrapper

Tags: swift, uitableview, concurrency, observable, combine

I found some unexpected behavior when using `@Published` to listen for view model's updates. Here's what I found:

```
// My View Model Class
class NotificationsViewModel {
    // MARK: - Properties

    @Published private(set) var notifications = [NotificationData]()

    // MARK: - APIs

    func fetchAllNotifications() {
        Task {
            do {
                // This does a network call to get all the notifications.
                notifications = try await NotificationsService.shared.getAllNotifications()
            } catch {
                printError(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

class NotificationsViewController: UIViewController {
    private let viewModel = NotificationsViewModel()
    // Here are some more properties..

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // This sets up the UI, such as adding a table view.
        configureUI()
        // This binds the current VC to the View Model.
        bindToViewModel()
    }

    func bindToViewModel() {
        viewModel.fetchAllNotifications()
        viewModel.$notifications.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).sink { [weak self] notifs in
            if self?.viewModel.notifications.count != notifs.count {
                print("debug: notifs.count - \(notifs.count), viewModel.notifications.count - \(self?.viewModel.notifications.count)")
            }
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, sometimes the table view is empty, even if there are notifications for my user. After some debugging, I found when I try to reload the table view after `viewModel.$notifications` notifies my VC about the updates, **the actual `viewModel.notifications` property didn't get updated, while the `notifs` in the subscription receive handler is correctly updated.**

A sample output of my issue is: `debug: notifs.count - 8, viewModel.notifications.count - Optional(0)`

Is this due to some race condition of `@Published` property? And what is the best practice of solving this issue? I know I can add a `didSet` to `notifications` and imperatively asks my VC to refresh itself, or simply call `self?.tableView.reloadData()` in the next main runloop. But neither of them look clean.

Comment: You need to have `class NotificationsViewModel: ObservableObject {...}` if you want to use `@Published`. This is primarily for use in SwiftUI Views. Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your SwiftUI app:  [Monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app). If you have a UIKit App this is not relevant.

Comment: That floating Task is a perfect source of a race condition. Also you should likely use @MainActor on that funcrion to try and sync Combine with async/await. They usually dont work together so AsyncStream is likely a better option.

Comment: Hi @workingdogsupportUkraine , I tried `ObservableObject` and do `viewModel.objectWillChange.sink(XXX)` but it doesn't solve the issue either

Comment: @loremipsum I can reproduce the issue if I change `fetchAllNotifications` function to always run on Main Actor by `Task {@MainActor in XXX }`

Comment: Making it an `ObservableObject` is _not_ required for using `@Published`, and doesn't change the semantics of how `@Published` works besides hooking it up to `objectWillChange`. `@Published` is basically just a property wrapper on `CurrentValueSubject`.

Answer (score 0):

The notification of an `@Published` property occurs in the `willSet` handler for the property.  That means that the value of the property does not actually change until after all the notifications are sent.

Inside of your `sink` call where you ask for `self?.viewModel.notifications` you are getting the previous value of `notifications`, not the new value that is to be stored in the property.  The new value is **not** available in your sink method.

If you want to use Combine to post notifications, use a `CurrentValueSubject` instead of an `@Published` property.  `@Published` is really aimed at syntax sugar for SwiftUI not as a general publish/subscribe mechanism for models.

I would recommend using `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` and not using `reloadData`.  Reloading the table kicks off a lot of work, all the work the OS did to get ready to draw is re-done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For `The notification of an @Published property occurs in the willSet handler for the property.`, this sounds like the behavior should then be deterministic and I should always reproduce my issue. But this is not the case, I only reproduce the issue once in a while (i.e. the View Model actually has the updated values for most of the time). Therefore I feel the behavior is not deterministic, which seems to be caused by some race condition in the implementation of @Published property wrapper.

Comment: That could be the case.  Or you are running into a problem caused by the fact that the change happens on one thread and the notification is received on the main thread.  It doesn't really change my recommendation.  I recommend that you do not use `@Published` as a general observer pattern (it's for SwiftUI) and you would probably be better served using one of the DataSource objects to handle updates rather than reloading the view every time.